# set right position in a draggable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, position, draggable

What i'm tryinjg to do:

Turn a div as draggable , then make a button to reset her position as default.

the question is, why i cant set the `right` position of a absolute div, after i set as draggable ?

**edit:** dragg the div first and then click in the button.

```
$('div').draggable();
$('#button').click(function(){
   $('div').draggable('destroy').css({ // destroy was only a test
       top: 0,
       right: 0 // nothing happens
   });
});
```

[**jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9uLCY/5/).

the position only work if i use `left`.

**edit 2:** the reason i'm not using the left position, its because if i zoom in, will overlay other things. Any tips, be my guest.

What i'm missing ?

Comment: I think I don't understand your question..

Comment: @Gabriel Santos: open jsfiddle demo as i say, drag the div and click the button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `$.draggable()` sets `left` as you drag the div around, and it stays set after you call `$.draggable('destroy')`

Just reset left using `left: auto;` http://jsfiddle.net/9uLCY/7/

```
$('div').draggable();
$('#button').click(function(){
   $('div').draggable('destroy').css({
        top: 0,
        left: 'auto',
        right: 0
    });
});
```

Comment: funny that `animate()` dosent work like `css` , the `left` stay on the same position.

Comment: `$.css()` only sets CSS properties. `$.animate` is smarter, it knows that if you're animating the left, the right needs to be auto and vice-versa

Answer (score 1):

Because there's still a "left" value on your draggable element which takes precedence over the "right" value.  You need to "unset" the left value

Answer (score 0):

First reset the left position to `auto`, as there is still a left position from the draggable method, then set the right position.

Comment: Resetting to 0 won't help, you need to reset it to `auto` so there's no conflict between `left, right and width`